# Change Rhythmbox MPEG-4 Audio (".m4a") Bitrate?

Tags: rhythmbox

How can I change the quality (bitrate) settings, when ripping in MPEG-4 Audio (".m4a") via Rhythmbox 3.4.4?

When I try to do so, the quality-selection has a greyed-out box that says "Default settings":
[image: Rhythmbox Preferences (Music)]

I want to be able to "rip" my CDs at 256kbps, which is the same quality used for the "iTunes Plus" format in Apple's iTunes / Music software...